# Rotate/Translate object in local space

Tags: mathematics, rotation, movement, transformation

I am just trying to create a movementcontroller class for game entities. These class should  transform the entity affected by the mouse and keyboard input. I am able to calculate the changed rotation and the new globalPosition. Then I multiply:

```
 newGlobalMatrix = changedRotationMatrix * oldGlobalMatrix;
 newGlobalMatrix = MatrixSetPosition(newPosition);
```

The problem is that the object rotates around the global axis and not around the local axis.

I use XNAMath for the matrix calculation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Translate along local axis](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31705/translate-along-local-axis)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct order to multiply scale, rotation and translation matrices for a proper world matrix?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16719/what-is-the-correct-order-to-multiply-scale-rotation-and-translation-matrices-f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe sounds like you are applying your local rotation after the global transformation has already been applied.

You need to apply the local transformation first - try flipping the order of multiplication of your matrices.